# HTML File not showing images when served through webserver, but if I directly open the html file in the browser it works

Tags: java, html, webserver

I am working on teaching myself a Web Server. My Web server serves html files right now, and that's it. I tried adding an image to the file, and it is not showing up (it's just the empty box with the X). However, if I directly open the html file through my browser it works just fine.

```html
<img src="image.jpg" width = "120" height = "90"/>
```

*note, this image is in the same folder as the server, hence the filename alone.

The way my web server works is it writes each line, one-by-one from the html file to the browser. Using this method, will the images not function properly? Is there something else I need to do for this to work?

The basic code that is writing the html lines to the browser are as follows:

```java
while ((lines = buffRead.readLine()) != null){

    outStream.write(lines.getBytes());

}
```

Comment: Tried `<img src="/image.jpg" width = "120" height = "90"/>` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most probably nothing wrong with the code that write the html line. Well, besides the spaces around the `=`. You may want to delete them.

However there is simply no image where you say one is, when you use the web server.

You say with that line: Hey browser, try to fetch an image named image.jpg. You will find it right on the same directory level as this html. Go for it.

It then tries and fails. Most probably because there is no such file, or you application does not know how to serve the file.

Have you tried to directly load the image in you browser? Like `http://yourhost/image.jpg` - or if you are in a sub directory `http://yourhost/yourdirectory/image.jpg`?

Comment: I haven't yet implemented the part of the server which will serve image files, but that's my next step. I just assumed that if there was an image in the html file, it would automatically display it. I assumed this because it display just fine when I open the html file directly (without the server).

Comment: No, if you run your code through an implemented web server, your server has to deliver all the files. The browser does not know your filesystem in this case.

Comment: Kai that is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you so much. I was tipped off on this idea when I saw the get method was running twice automatically, once for the html file and once for the image file. Thank you!